# how to reset sessionStorage items from all open tabs in angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I need a ts code to logout from every tab opened. Currently i am using  a code which will allow all tab to have sessionStorage items.
But when i try to logout by resetting sessionStorage from once tab its not working.

Answer (score 0):

sessionStorage stotes the data individually for each tab, try to use cookie to store login related information.

You may use localStorage as well, but store data will not implicitly expire when you close your browser.

There are few good packages available for doing cookie operation in Angular as follows.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service

Comment: But cookie is not secure

Comment: You can store token in cookie and send it in header, at server side you can verify token from header. so there would not be any security issues, specific to XSRF.